# Type with one record as string and any others as specified

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

```
type A<T> = {
  id: string
} & Record<string, T>


const test: A<number> = {
  id: 'dd',
  anyKey: 33
}
```

// Error: TS2322: Type { id: string; anyKey: number; } is not assignable to type A
Type { id: string; anyKey: number; } is not assignable to type Record<string, number>
Property id is incompatible with index signature.
Type string is not assignable to type number

Why i got this error and how to get type that have only one value as string and others as specified?

Comment: This is currently impossible, see the linked q/a for the relevant missing feature github issue and the various workarounds that exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting the error message is that `Record<string, T>` and `id: string` are overlapping, since `id` is a string key.

`Record<string, T>` could also be `id: number` in this scenario.
You cannot have both `id: number` and `id: string` specified for one type.
How would you access the property based on its type alone?
You can't do `(test as { id: number }).id` or some magic like that to get a different value, typescript does not allow that, it wouldn't even make sense conceptually.

It is more of a design / structure problem, if you need an object with this kind of specificity like `id: string`, try separate it from the `Record<string, T>` where anything could go.